# Dictionaries - Check key for multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

in my program (that searches for specific keys) i want to implement that it terminates if the key has more than one value. How can i check a key for multiple values?

edit: thanks for clearing up my mistake.
It seems my values are lists. In that case how can i check for multiple items in the list that is my value?

Comment: You should be more specific with your problem. Dictionaries can only have one value per key, if you try to assign a second value, the first will be overwritten. Are your values lists?

Comment: yes, it seems my values are lists. thank you for the clarification. i will edit my post to specify/correct my question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) builtin in python, you can check the length of a list. If the length of the value is more then 1 then there are more then one value in the list.

```
for key in dictionary: # loop through all the keys
    value = dictionary[key]   # get value for the key
    if len(value) > 1:        
        break                 # stop loop if list length is more than 1
```

Note that this assumes that *every* value in the dictionary is a list or container.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a dictionary key to have more than one value: either the key is not present in the dictionary, so it has no value, or it is present, and it has one value.

That value may be a tuple, list, dictionary, etc., which contains multiple values, but it is *still one value* itself. The value may also be `None` which can be a marker for no value, but it is still a value.

As @Ulisha's comment said, if you try to assign a new value to a key, the new value will just replace the old value. Again, there can be at most one value for a given key, although there are ways to *simulate* multiple values by using container objects such a tuple, list, or dict.

---

If you are looking at a specific item and you want to test if it is a list, you can use

```
if isinstance(item, list):
```

This will also catch items that have a type that descends from list, such as a priority queue. If you want to expand that to also detect tuples, dicts, sets, and most other "containers", you can use

```
if isinstance(item, collections.Container):
```

For this you will, of course, need to import the `collections` module.

Remember that even if the item is a list, it may have no, one, or multiple items.